# Replacing alternate 2 digits of a number with dot in Polymer 3

Tags: numbers, masking

I want to replace alternate 2 digit of a number with a dot in polymer 3. I tried something but it is not working as i wanted. Please help.

before masking : 56789012
after masking : 5..8..1.

Comment: that sounds like you want to use numeral.js

Comment: Hi pascal, can you please help me in finding the solution. I have tried something like this but it is not working.
maskingfield (str) {
  for(var j=0;j<str.length;j++){
   if(j/3 != 0){
    return str[j] = '*';
   }
   else{
    return str;
   }
   
  }
 }
P.s : i used '*' instead of '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go have fun with it:

```
var maskingfield = function (str) {
    var out = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
        if (j % 3 === 1 || j % 3 === 2) {
            out += '.';
        } else {
            out += str[j];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Calling : `maskingfield("56789012")` will give you "5..8..1."